# how to convert the bool to nullable bool (bool?)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, linq-to-entities

i have a table provider with column

```
                 implied(tiny int)(something like nullable bool)
                 providerid(int)
```

I have a form and i have check box

I am doing winforms applications using c# ..

i am using enitities and my dbcontext name is dbcontext

How to covert  bool to nullable bool(bool?)   in C sharp.

I have tried this way

```
      if (chkbox.checked == true)

            bool yes = 0;
        else

          bool   yes = 1;

        dbcontext.implied = yes;
```

but got an error

```
Cannot convert bool to bool?
```

Comment: That code isn't valid C# in various ways, and you haven't said anything about where you got the error. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question.

Comment: Sounds very strange. Could you post some code that actually exhibits the problem? Your code sample obviously doesn't compile. The scope of `yes` is too small and doesn't reach the line where you assign `yes` to `implied`, and normally `bool` gets converted to `bool?` implicitly.

Comment: Straight assignment should work

Comment: I am sorry guys for not providing information.... the information is too big...thas why i am not able  to provide that one ....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Explicitly cast to a `bool?`

```
bool b = true;
bool? b2 = (bool?)b;
```

In case it's of interest, you can convert `bool?` to `bool`. You can do this by first checking `HasValue` which will return `false` if it's null or `true` if it is not null.

If it does have a value, you can cast to a bool.

```
bool? b = null;
if (b.HasValue == false) // it's null
{
  //initialize b 
  b = false;
}
else if((bool)b == true)
{
  // do whatever
}
```

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384091.aspx for bool? to bool conversion.

Answer (score 3):

`dbcontext.implied = new Nullable<bool>(yes);`

Answer (score 3):

Can directly do something like

```
bool result = true;
bool? toBindData = (bool?)result;
```

Comment: The cast should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Convert.ToBoolean(Your checkBox)**

Below how I tested on my `DataGridView` to check `CheckBox` column and it works fine.

```
if ( Convert.ToBoolean( dgv.Rows[r].Cells["Delete"].Value))
{
    //Do work;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(chkbox.checked) == true)
```

Or a simpler version:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(chkbox.checked))
```

as the default condition anticipates the **Truth** of the statement.

Dependencies:

```
using.System;
```